# 360 videos issue in WebView on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webview, youtube

I'm working for a school project and I'm developing my first iOS app.
The app shows our website that have a 360 videos, hosted by YouTube. 
My problem is that 360 videos don't work in WebView so I have to open in YouTube app but I'm not able to do that. 
Can you help me please?

My code is the following

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let url = URL(string: "mysite")
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!) 
        webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You must make your own video player and that´s hard. I think that you should just you [open Youtube app](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/YouTubeLinks/YouTubeLinks.html).

Comment: @SamuelTulach thank you very much!